# Using Solve with Mod

Tags: equation-solving

I'm new to *Mathematica*, and it seems like what I'm doing should be a simple operation, but I can't seem to get it to work, or return the right result. I'm assuming I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but haven't been able to find what.

Two different problems I've tried to solve:

$3 = 13^x \mod 71$

```
Solve[3 == Mod[13^x, 71], x, Integers]
(* {{x->ConditionalExpression[24+70 C[1],C[1]∈Integers&&C[1]>=0]}} *)
```

I know from brute forcing 24 is an answer:

$59 = 3^x \mod 71$

```
Solve[59 == Mod[3^x, 71], x, Integers]
```

No result returned.

I haven't brute forced this yet, but its gotta line up eventually...

Comment: Well, as far as the first one goes, it works. What's the problem with that one? As far as the second, maybe there's no solution?

Comment: The Modulus documentation in my opinion is too poor.  It just has some random examples in there, doesn't show the actual problem its going to solve.  I guess I expected the first one to be a cleaner answer than what it returned, but maybe thats just how it goes.  Turns out I'm solving the wrong equation for the second.  Anyway, was more looking for if there is a better/more effective way of solving this.

Comment: The `{}` returned by `Solve` indicates there are no `x` that solve the equation.

Comment: Brute force: `Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Table[Mod[3^x, 71], {x, 70}]`

Comment: It seems to me `Solve` is working exactly as it is supposed to.  The `C[1]` is a parameter, that parametrizes the infinitely many solutions of the equation.  You can set it to any nonnegative integer with a replacement like this `sol /. C[1] -> 0`.

Comment: The function for this is `MultiplicativeOrder`. So: `In[639]:= MultiplicativeOrder[13, 71, 3]

Out[639]= 24

In[641]:= MultiplicativeOrder[3, 71, 59]

Out[641]= MultiplicativeOrder[3, 71, 59]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FindInstance`, with your 1st equation

```
FindInstance[3 == Mod[13^x, 71], x, Integers]
```

gives

> `{{x -> 24}}`

but with your 2nd equation

```
FindInstance[59 == Mod[3^x, 71], x, Integers]
```

gives

`{}`

because there is no integer solution. `Mod[3^x, 71]` cycles through the set

> ```
> {3, 9, 27, 10, 30, 19, 57, 29, 16, 48, 2, 6, 18, 54, 20, 60, 38, 43,
>  58, 32, 25, 4, 12, 36, 37, 40, 49, 5, 15, 45, 64, 50, 8, 24, 1}
> ```

which does not contain 59.

Comment: Hmm, this is closer to what I was expecting.  Obviously I still have a lot to learn...  Thanks for the help!